# HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Failed to read Parquet file. Athena version 3 is causing this issue when using a where clause on certain strings

Tags: amazon-athena

When running a sql query in Athena version 2 I was able to run the query "select * from db.table where id_enabled = 'true'" and now that version 3 has been implemented I get the HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Failed to read Parquet file error. The types are type string and the queries where 'inactive' or where 'false' both work. I have been using the workaround where id_enabled like '%true%' which succeeds but would like to figure out the actual way to fix the table in Athena version 3.

Comment: Actually, I was able to fix the issue. Nevermind

Comment: Feel free to answer your question with the solution, @dmo2412.

Comment: @dmo2412 datatype mismatch or what was the solution?

Comment: @leon22 Needed to add this field to the DDL: WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'parquet.ignore.statistics'='true')